# Using EPPlus 4.501 beta, when I try to save a .xlsx file as a .xlsm file, I get message that the file format is invalid

Tags: excel, vba, epplus

I'm simply trying to save a .xlsx file as a .xlsm file in preparation to add vba code to it and I get a message saying that the file type is invalid and to check if the file is corrupt.

Here's the code:

```
      var excelFile = new FileInfo(@"wwwroot/SubmissionFiles/23477-1/Financial_Report_0001091596.xlsx");
        using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(excelFile))
        {
            //pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("VBA Code");
            //pck.Workbook.CreateVBAProject();                
            pck.SaveAs(new System.IO.FileInfo(@"wwwroot/SubmissionFiles/23477-1/Financial_Report_0001091596.xlsm"));
        }
```

When I attempt to open the file manually, I get the following error message:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPYYE.png)

I'm using Excel 2013 and the code is in VS 2017 targeting .NET Core 2.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get a code page into that workbook before you can actually save it with the .xlsm extension.

1. Try adding a new code page with a simple routine.
2. Try inserting a boilerplate code page.

Then save.

Comment: I added the following code:

               `pck.Workbook.CreateVBAProject();
                pck.Workbook.CodeModule.Code = "'test code";`

When I try to open it, it says "we found a problem with some content in filename. Do you want to try to recover as much as you can?" When I say yes, it says Excel was able to open the by repairing or removing the unreadable content and underneath it says: Removed Part: /xl/vbaProject.bin part.  (Visual Basic for Applications (VBA))

Comment: The problem seems to be in the source excel sheet. It can be opened and saved as a .xlsm manually with no problems, but when I try to use code, I get errors. When I try the same approach with a brand new .xlsx file I just created, I get no problems. The source workbook has many many sheets and no VBA code, so I'm not sure what's wrong with it that is causing epplus to not be able to produce a .xlsm version of it that isn't corrupted.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to use Excel.Interop to get this to work. I don't know why I couldn't get Epplus to work on this file.

Comment: When you run the code.  Can you make the workbook visible?

Maybe .... instead of trying to do a lot of stuff at one time ... just do one thing at a time.

1.  Ok you have a workbook open
2.  Make it visible
3.  The code above looks to add only a worksheet to the workbook.
4.  The next line of code ( not sure what it's doing ) but somehow you need to get a reference to the vbaproject and "ADD" a code page "MODULE"
5.  Then add a valid routine like "Sub Test():End Sub"

Then save it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'll need to come back to this as I have a deadline and have it working with interop; once I have some time, I'll try to get it working with Epplus.